# If function $f , xf(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, define $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$. If $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f=0$, prove $F$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis

If function $f $and $ xf(x)$ are both $\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, define $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$. If $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f=0$, how to prove $F$ is integrable?

My thought is:  $$\int_{-\infty}^b |\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt|dx\leq \int_{-\infty}^b \int_{-\infty}^x |f(t)|dtdx=\int_{-\infty}^b\int_t^b |f(t)|dxdt=\int_{-\infty}^b(b-t)|f(t)|dt=\int_{-\infty}^bb|f(t)|dt-\int_{-\infty}^bt|f(t)|dt$$

we have $ \int_{-\infty}^bt|f(t)|dt<\infty,\forall b$ but we don't know $b\int_{-\infty}^b|f(t)|dt<\infty $ when $b\rightarrow +\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You already lost every chance of bounding your integral when you used the triangle inequality in the first step. This kills the oscillation of $f$ that makes it have mean zero. Note that without the mean-zero assumption, the statement is wrong!

Decompose $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt \right| dx$ as $\int_{-L}^R = \int_{-L}^0 + \int_0^R$ with $L,R\rightarrow\infty$.

In the first integral use the triangle inequality and integration by parts (possible by absolute continuity of the primitive).

In the second use first the mean-zero property
$$\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt = -\int_x^\infty f(t) dt$$
and *then* triangle inequality and proceed as before.

Comment: Can you say more clearly? How to integral by parts and get the answer?

Comment: $\int_{-L}^0 G(x) dx=LG(-L)-\int_{-L}^0 x |f(x)| dx$ where $G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x |f(t)|dt$. Note that $G$ is absolutely continuous and $G^\prime(x)=|f(x)|$ for a.e. $x$. @user157361

Comment: As you said, I got $\int_0^R\int_x^\infty |f|dtdx=R||f||_1-RG(R)+\int_0^R x|f(x)|dx$, I don't know why the sum of the two parts is finite when $R,L\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: There should not be a term $R\|f\|_1$. You should get $R \int_R^\infty |f(t)|dt$ for the boundary term which is bounded by $\int_R^\infty t|f(t)|dt$ which converges to $0$ by assumption. Summing up, the sum of the two parts is bounded by $\int_{-L}^R |xf(x)|dx\le \|xf\|_1<\infty$ plus the boundary terms which go to zero as $L,R\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I got it, you are down, thank you.